# Is there any idiom to describe something that happened recently?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Is there any idiom to describe something that happened recently? I am looking for something exactly synonymous with "recently", I googled it alot, however i didn't find what exactly i was looking for.

Example Sentence:

> It happened ____________ [**recently**].

(please provide a accurate replacement of the word "recently", A word or idiom that could be used as an exact alternative)

Comment: If you want something "exactly synonymous" with *recently*, what's wrong with the word *recently* itself?

Comment: And it might help to show us which of your choices hadn't matched what you had wanted so that we can start to nail down one that does. Although the answer below, "the other day," sounds pretty good to me.

Comment: "not [too/so] long ago".

Comment: You should have used a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/recently).

Answer (score 1):

You may use "***a while ago/back***" as a substitute. Although it means “*a short or moderate time ago*”, I guess it still works because *recently* itself is subjective.

dictionary.com:

> **[a while back](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/a-while-back)**
>   *Also*, **a while ago**.
>   Some time in the past, as in I ran into Barbara a while back but didn't get her new address, or John wrote me
>   a while ago about his new baby.
>   This term uses a while in the sense
>   of “a short or moderate time,” a usage dating from about 1300.
>
> The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary Copyright © 2002, 2001, 1995
>   by Houghton Mifflin Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company.

Answer (score 0):

"the other day"

> **other day, the**
>
> *One day recently, a short time ago*, as in *I saw her in the museum the other day*. This term originally meant either “the next day” or “the preceding day” (tomorrow or yesterday). In its current meaning it was first recorded in 1421.

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

***Lately, not too long ago***
*Lately, not too long ago*, as in *I saw my friend not too long ago or lately I've been feeling tired and bored or everything.*